# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, sockets

I've tried to connect to my local machine every time I try and run my program.
I am a nub, so it's probably a simple mistake somewhere.

```
def connect(self):
    self.conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.conn.connect((self.host,self.port))
```

That is the code causing the error.
The host and port are defined.
Why is it giving me this error report?

[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you haven't opened the port you are trying to connect to, nothing is listening there. If you're trying to connect to a web or ftp server, start it first. If you're trying to connect to another port, you need to write a server application too.

Comment: Thank you. I had a server running, but I had it configured differently (port number was off).