# How to get networked test app to run under Jenkins user

Tags: jenkins

I have a build running under Jenkins (Windows 7) that builds a C++ application.  I wrote a small test app in python that runs the application after it is built and tests its networking capabilities.  The problem is that the python script fails with

> socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The test app works fine if I run it locally (it's only connecting on localhost 127.0.0.1) but it always fails when run under Jenkins.

I thought it was the firewall preventing the connection, but I discovered that the firewall has been turned off on the build machine.

I also have the Jenkins service logging in with an account that has admin access.  I don't know where else to look.

Is it possible to run an app that accesses the local network during a Jenkins build?

**Update:**
As it turns out, my issue has nothing to do with networking, as far as I can tell.  The C++ app tries to setup some DirectX9 services and is blocked from doing so under the user privileges provided by Jenkins.  As a result, it quits before it even gets to setting up the networking.  Now I have a different problem to solve.

Comment: Did you look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6782732/1464763

Comment: @DavidLevesque - I read through it and I double checked a number of things (order of launch, port numbers and such) but it turns out that wasn't the issue.  See my update.

Comment: If you are running jenkins as windows service, then try to run it from command line. There are some privilege issues when Jenkins runs as Windows Service.

Comment: @NotAgain - I removed the windows service and tried running it from the command line, but when I did that, Jenkins came up a clean slate, with no configuration and no jobs.  I would have thought it would load by default its configuration from config.xml, but apparently that isn't the case.

Comment: @NotAgain - I figured it out.  Needed to set the JENKINS_HOME variable.

Comment: @NotAgain - Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you post the first error message which comes while setting up DirectX9 services?

Comment: @NotAgain - Calling GetDeviceCaps(0, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &d3dCaps) immediately after calling Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION) returns D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE.