# Why can't I send a mail to myself using python smtplib?

Tags: python, smtp, python-2.7

I am using this code taken from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html):

```
import smtplib

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = prompt("From: ")
toaddrs  = prompt("To: ").split()
print "Enter message, end with ^D (Unix) or ^Z (Windows):"

# Add the From: and To: headers at the start!
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
while 1:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line:
        break
    msg = msg + line

print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))

server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

I put my gmail mail account in the sender and in the reciver but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/smtpExample.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 302, in connect

    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not running [SMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Outgoing_mail_SMTP_server) on your machine.

see: [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532335/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: but if you actually intend on these mails reaching anyone, you're better of using you provider's SMTP server.

Comment: what do you mean by provider? ISP? Is this ok? 
http://geekswithblogs.net/ferdous/archive/2011/03/15/smtp-setup-for-windows-7.aspx

Comment: @ZoZo123: I mean your email provider, like eg Gmail: http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-through-gmail-with-python/