# Send mail using Python- Error

Tags: python-2.7, email

I quite new in programing in python. When i try to send an e-mail using python 2.7, i get an error:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

msg = MIMEText("Hello There!")
msg['Subject'] = 'A Test Message'
msg['From']='kolsason7@walla.com'
msg['To'] = 'yaron148@gmail.com'
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail('kolsason7@walla.com',['yaron148@gmail.com'],msg.as_string())
print("Message Sent!")

  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
error: [Errno 10061] 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP       

try:
    sender = 'xxx@gmail.com'
    receivers = ['xxx.com']

    message = """ this message sending from python
    for testing purpose
    """
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.login('xxx','xxx')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
    smtpObj.quit()
    print "Successfully sent email"
    except smtplib.SMTPException,error:
    print str(error)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

If u ran this code u would see a error message like this stating that google is not allowing u to login via code

Things to change in gmail:

1.Login to gmail

2.Go to this link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

3.Click enable then retry the code

Hopes it help :)

But there are security threats if u enable it

Answer (score 1):

Quoting this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532340/3083243)

> It's because you haven't opened the port you are trying to connect to,
>   nothing is listening there. If you're trying to connect to a web or
>   ftp server, start it first. If you're trying to connect to another
>   port, you need to write a server application too.

And see a similar solved problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012303/why-cant-i-send-a-mail-to-myself-using-python-smtplib)

Answer (score 0):

Your smtp server is set as localhost, are you sure it's right ?
The error is a "connection opening".
You may have to find a username/password/address/port combination for the SMTP server that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have used is not designed to be run on Windows, it is designed to be run on Linux where there is (usually) a service listening on port 25 at localhost.

For Windows, you'll need to connect to an actual mail server before you can send messages.

Comment: i don't know how to do it