# Python Email, [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I want to send a mail in using python, below is my code, but I got the error 10061 at the end, hope anyone can help me, thanks!

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = 'XXX@XX.com'
toaddrs  = 'XXX@XX.com    '
msg = 'Why,Oh why!'
username = 'XXXXXX'
password = 'XXXXXX'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

error msg:socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532335/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: Its not duplicate of the mentioned question. This question is more specific to gmail services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Cid-EL, **[You have to enable less secure apps in GMAIL settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)**

However, It's not secure to turn on that perticular option.

Gmail provides API's to perform mail operations. GMAIL API's are supported in many languages.

For Python API : [Python with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

For Java API's  : [Java with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

**Little more effort but you can have a secure connection !!**

Step 1: Turn on the GMAIL API

Step 2: Install Google client library

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Step 3: Code sample to send a mail using GMAIL API

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
   import argparse
   flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
   flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials 
# at ~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = "https://mail.google.com/"
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
  """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

  If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
  the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

  Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
  """
   home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
   credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
   if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
      os.makedirs(credential_dir)
   credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

   store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
   credentials = store.get()
   if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
      flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
      flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
      if flags:
         credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
      else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
         credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
      print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
   return credentials

# create a message
def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
  """
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}

#send message 
def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
    """Send an email message.

    Args:
     service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
     user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
     can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     message: Message to be sent.

    Returns:
     Sent Message.
    """
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        #print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
        return message
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
       Send a mail using gmail API
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    msg_body = "test message"

    message = CreateMessage("xxxxx@gmail.com", "yyy@gmail.com", "Status report of opened tickets", msg_body)
   
    SendMessage(service, "me", message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi just Authentication successful for GMAIL API, and what's the next step? How can I send a mail with this API, sorry for the stupid question

Comment: Its okay, have you created account in google developer console ?

Comment: YES I have, just want to know what's step? could you please give me some code about how to call the GMAIL API or how to use the API

Comment: @Emon i've updated the answer, when you run for the first time, it will open a browser and you have to give the permission there. 
let me know if it won't work

Comment: Sorry for my stupid. but this line     except errors.HttpError, error:
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)   is error, how to define the errors?

Comment: @Emon Please check whether your indentation is correct

Comment: @Emon keep both client.json and current python file in the home directory

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Gmail and other companies have security to prevent emails being sent from unknown sources, but [this link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) can turn that kind of security off.

There you can modify the account so it will accept the email.

I use this code to send email:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_address = 'johndoe@gmail.com'

to_address = 'johndoe@gmail.com'

message = MIMEMultipart('Foobar')

epos_liggaam['Subject'] = 'Foobar'

message['From'] = from_address

message['To'] = to_address

content = MIMEText('Some message content', 'plain')

message.attach(content)

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login(from_address, 'password')

mail.sendmail(from_address,to_address, message.as_string())

mail.close()
```

Comment: Pls note that my first language is not english, so some of the variables may have weird names... thanks

Comment: as mentioned by Cid-EL you have to enable less secure apps. Since you are using gmail. You can also use GMAIL API's

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I use turn one the lesssecureapps and use your codes, but still got the same error msg.:(

Comment: did you went to the link and chose turn on, then saved the changes and tried it? couse i had the excact error u had some time ago, and that code worked quite well.