# Django send Gmail using.core.mail import send_mail: ConnectionRefusedError: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: django, email, view, gmail, send

In gmail account security I turned **ON** the following:

Access to less secure apps **AND**

Signing in with 2-Step Verification

In view file:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
subject = 'Thank you for registering to our site'
message = ' it  means a world to us '
email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list = ['john.doe@gmail.com', ]
send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
```

In settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’
EMAIL_HOST = ‘smtp.gmail.com’
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ‘myemailaddress@gmail.com’
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘mypassword’
```

Cannot figure out why getting the error:

ConnectionRefusedError at /email_link_spi/951437/
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960035/python-email-errno-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machi) it might help

Answer (score 0):

You can either turn less secure apps to ON , or enable two step verification .. if you prefer enable two step verification then you can create an app password and give that password in EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.

Comment: @kakam, Not sure you read the first 3 lines of my post.  I have turned on "Access to Less Secure Apps" and also turned on "Signing in with 2-Step Verification"  I also created an app password.  None of this work and still encounter the error.